# Google Maps Android API v2, Marker title/snippet wrong display

Tags: android, google-maps, internationalization, google-places-api

I use Google Maps Android API v2 with Android to show current position with nearby markers.
Nearby places locations and titles are received using Google Places API.

The problem is that non-english names at title/snippet are shown in fail way.
For the instance, Hebrew names.

The sreenshot is attached.

[image: Screenshot])

Comment: It may be that Maps V2 does not have proper RTL support. Do you encounter problems with LTR languages?

Comment: Sure I'm not, mate. Seems that the issue applies only to i18n.

Comment: Again, my theory is not i18n in general, but RTL vs. LTR languages. Proper RTL support is relatively new in Android, and Maps V2 may have messed it up. You could use an `InfoWindowAdapter` to create your own contents of the map balloon, where you do a better job than the built-in stuff with RTL.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I think so too that that's RTL issue. But listen I have no suitable data locations to check all the languages or mostly all.. Nevertheless English, Russian have good looks. Arabic, Hebrew are not. All the things are against RTL, right.

Comment: That certainly feels like an RTL issue.

Comment: `@CommonsWare` have you experience with implement `InfoWindowAdapter` to share? I'll accept your answer than.

Comment: Hey oleg,Im using also Google Maps Android API v2 for google maps. and im trying to use places api but when i post request it return Acces_denied.

My question if you use the same key of Google Maps Android API v2 for the request to google places like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,fd&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=true/false&key=<my key>

thanks
Gil

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Arabic and Hebrew are causing problems, and English and Russian are not, I am going to guess that something is broken in the default info window implementation with respect to right-to-left (RTL) languages. Particularly if you are running your tests on Android 4.2, it may be that Maps V2's default info window contents have incorrectly applied the various RTL-related attributes.

Fortunately, you can supply your own info window contents, by implementing `InfoWindowAdapter` and having `getInfoContents()` return the `View` that you want to use in the info window.

For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Popups) (from tomorrow's update to my book) shows customizing the info window using this `InfoWindowAdapter`:

```
class PopupAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {
  LayoutInflater inflater=null;

  PopupAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
    this.inflater=inflater;
  }

  @Override
  public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    return(null);
  }

  @Override
  public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    View popup=inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

    TextView tv=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.title);

    tv.setText(marker.getTitle());
    tv=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
    tv.setText(marker.getSnippet());

    return(popup);
  }
}
```

If you want to replace the whole window, you would have `getInfoWindow()` return a `View`. If `getInfoWindow()` returns `null`, `getInfoContents()` is used for the contents of the window. You then attach an instance of `InfoWindowAdapter` via `setInfoWindowAdapter()` on your `GoogleMap`.

In your case, you could use your own layout to make sure that you are implementing RTL correctly. That should, in principle, clear up this problem. It is conceivable that Maps V2 does something strange that breaks RTL code that normally should work, in which case you'd need to [file an issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list).

Comment: I only will add that in my case I should make this that manner:

       @Override
   public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    TextView info = new TextView(ShareLocation.this);
    info.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
      FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    info.setText(marker.getTitle() + "\n" + marker.getSnippet());
    info.setTextColor(ShareLocation.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

    return info;
   }

Works beautiful. And the main secret is why google missed this way :-)

Comment: @OlegPreobrazhenskyy, where you able to make Hebrew work ? I am trying with my own layout using GetInfoWindow, and while English looks ok, Hebrew in TextView is not seen at all... Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a way to set a utf8 string ? (Arabic Lang)

Comment: @S.M_Emamian: AFAIK, `TextView` supports Arabic strings. If you are encountering problems, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question showing your code, along with perhaps a screenshot illustrating any problems you are having.

Comment: @CommonsWare For Hebrew, this doesn't work. In order to make it work, I had to add  android:textDirection="locale" for each of the textViews. I have no idea though if it works fine on pre-API 17 .

Comment: It looks like Google fixed the issue according to the reported bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823358

Answer (score 2):

Adding more info regarding CommnsWare answer:

As of the moment I am writing this commend, it seems that the map itself is `layout_direction="LTR"` which means that your titles will not be flipped on RTL desktops. The solution is simple:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layoutDirection="locale"
>
    ....
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that I am using the locale's layout direction and not the inherited direction. I commented this on the corresponding Google bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5608#makechanges

Comment: "layoutDirection" is available from API 17. What would happen before? Also, I think it works only when setting textDirection for the textViews.

Comment: This problem doesn't appear to be fixed, even though it's 2020. The only thing that worked for me is this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that this bug occurs only on LinearLayout (which is very weird).

Try RelativeLayout instead, or, if you have API 17 and above, set textDirection for each of the TextViews, and it should work