# Google maps marker in other languages

Tags: java, android

i want to show a marker on google maps:

this is my code:

```
mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(location)
    .title(poi.getName()).snippet(poi.getDescription())
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image_item));
```

my google maps language is in hebrew (the street names)

however, when my poi.getName() returns string in hebrew it doesnt show me the title, however if the poi.getName() returns string in english it show the title on the marker...

what is the problem that the marker refuse to show Strings in other languages rather than english (like hebrew)

however when i click on location on google maps it shows me a marker with the street name in hebrew.. therefore i think that it's possible to show marker with other languages.

how can i implement that my marker will show Strings in other  languages?

thanks alot

Comment: Check this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121908/google-maps-android-api-v2-marker-title-snippet-wrong-display) for a possible solution.

Comment: thanks alot, i checked the answer there however it doesnt work for me..i can see that user named: @Shushu had the same problem..Is there another solution for this problem?  the google maps shows me title and snippest in hebrew when i click on address on google maps, So must be a solution, thanks alot

Comment: When you say it doesn't show the title do you mean the title is completely blank? Second, where do you get the string from (e.g. `SQLiteDatabase`)?